# Working of free() in C

Tags: c, linked-list, free

I have some trouble understanding on how the free() function in C works. What is think free() does is, as the name says, free the memory at the address which was passed as an argument. Then i tried the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

int main()
{
    struct node *first, *second, *temp;
    first = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    second = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp = first;
    first->data = 1;
    first->next = second;
    second->data = 2;
    second->next = NULL;
    free(first);
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above is a very basic implementation of linked list. I created two nodes, namely first and second, fed in the data, and linked them together. I then 'freed' the first node, and attempted to print the linked list.
I got the following output:

**0 

2**

So, here is my question, why is the second node being printed? If the first node was freed, then all the data and the next pointer should have been deleted. Even if I did

```
temp = first;
```

I just copied the address from first to temp. When I free first, whatever was stored there should be destroyed, including the address of the second node. So how am I still able to print the second node?

Comment: UB, and multi-dup :(

Comment: when you do a malloc() memory will be allocated from heap for your program .. once you free the memory using free() the memory will be given back to the available chunk so that other program can use that memory. It will not destroy the data written to that memory until and unless it will be over written by some other program.

Comment: You are probably being irritated why temp->data seems to be zeroed while temp->next isn't. This is just due to meta-data being written to the (data-part) of the allocated memory chunk on `free()` (the so-called _free-list_). and is _not_ a mechanism of destroying the data systematically on free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your assumption that:

> If the first node was freed, then all the data and the next pointer
>   should have been deleted.

You can free the first node, and that memory will return to the heap. It doesn't (necessarily) get modified in any way. In your example, the pointer to the second node happened to remain intact, so that you were still able to iterate to it. This is how you were able to print the first and second number in the list.

Basically, all free() does is to say "This process doesn't care about this block of memory any more". And then the operating system or something else can use it. Next time you use malloc(), it might give you this same block of memory back again.

This is all undefined behaviour, of course. That means it'll happily run, until it doesn't.

Comment: Why do you answer a very obvious duplicate?

Comment: The question has not been marked as a duplicate. Did I go wrong?

Comment: If you take a gander at the comments underneath it, you'll see that its been discussed before. The question is currently sitting at 4 close votes (1 more to close as dupe)(although you cant see that). In such cases where multiple people point out that its a duplicate you should abstain from answering.

Comment: All right, now I know. Thanks